# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STATIC

Tags: php

```
class Employee 
{
    public static $favSport = "Football";

    public static function watchTV()
    {
        echo "Watching ".static::$favSport;
    }
}

class Executive extends Employee 
{
    public static $favSport = "Polo";
}

echo Executive::watchTV();
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STATIC on line 7

Why do I get parse error & and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: What's the return of phpversion() ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The parse error here:

```
echo "Watching ".static::$favSport;
```

is because [late static bindings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) were introduced in PHP v5.3. Your php version (<5.3) doesn't recognize `static::$favSport`.

There isn't any way I can think of to fix it for PHP older than 5.3, other than with object inheritance (which isn't really a *fix* per se since it doesn't have anything to do with `static`)...

Comment: @Pekka: PHP 4 would choke on the `public` keyword :)

Comment: How about replacing `static` with the classname?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, but i used self in the place of static for my php version that's 5.2.1
well older than 5.3 http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php